# Why does this Free Monad Interpreter not resolve String to Id[A]

Tags: scala, csv, functional-programming, scala-cats, free-monad

I've been playing with Free Monads of Cats. I have written a DSL to process CSV Records. The primitive operation is to process CSV Record and I have written a helper `sequence` and `map2` functions for `processCSVRecords` operation myself. I want the return type of the case class to be generic type `R`. Below is the code that I'm using.

```
import cats.data.Coproduct
import cats.free.Free.inject
import cats.free.{Free, Inject}
import cats.{Id, ~>}
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord

object ProcessCSVActions {

  sealed trait ProcessCSV[A]

  case class ProcessCSVRecord[R](csvRecord: CSVRecord) extends ProcessCSV[R]

  class ProcessCSVs[F[_]](implicit I: Inject[ProcessCSV, F]) {

    private def sequence[S[_], A](fs: Stream[Free[S, A]]): Free[S, Stream[A]] =
      fs.reverse.foldLeft[Free[S, Stream[A]]](Free.pure[S, Stream[A]](Stream()))((b, a) => map2(a, b)(_ #:: _))

    private def map2[S[_], A, B, C](ra: Free[S, A], rb: Free[S, B])(f: (A, B) => C): Free[S, C] = for {
      a <- ra
      b <- rb
    } yield f(a, b)

    def processCSVRecord[R](csvRecord: CSVRecord): Free[F, R] =
      inject[ProcessCSV, F](ProcessCSVRecord[R](csvRecord))

    def processCSVRecords[R](csvRecords: Stream[CSVRecord]): Free[F, Stream[R]] = {
      val res: Stream[Free[F, R]] = for {
        csvRecord <- csvRecords
      } yield processCSVRecord[R](csvRecord)
      sequence[F, R](res)
    }


  }

  object ProcessCSVs {
    def apply[F[_]](implicit I: Inject[ProcessCSV, F]): ProcessCSVs[F] = new ProcessCSVs[F]
  }

  object StringInterpreterOfCSV extends (ProcessCSV ~> Id) {
    override def apply[A](fa: ProcessCSV[A]): Id[A] = fa match {
      case ProcessCSVRecord(csvRecord) => csvRecord.get(2)
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I try to compile the above code, I get the below error for my interpreter:

```
[scalac-2.11]  found   : String
[scalac-2.11]  required: cats.Id[A]
[scalac-2.11]     (which expands to)  A
[scalac-2.11]       case ProcessCSVRecord(csvRecord) => csvRecord.get(2)
[scalac-2.11]                                                        ^
[scalac-2.11] one error found
```

What is the proper way to handle `Stream` with `Free`?

Edit:

I've found a hack. I'm taking a param of type `R` in the case class.

```
  case class ProcessCSVRecord[R](csvRecord: CSVRecord, a:Option[R]) extends ProcessCSV[R]
  def processCSVRecord[R](csvRecord: CSVRecord): Free[F, R] =
      inject[ProcessCSV, F](ProcessCSVRecord[R](csvRecord, None))
```

In the interpreter, I'm explicitly giving the type that matches the result.

```
  object StringInterpreterOfCSV extends (ProcessCSV ~> Id) {
    override def apply[A](fa: ProcessCSV[A]): Id[A] = fa match {
      case ProcessCSVRecord(csvRecord, _: Option[String]) => csvRecord.get(2)
    }
  }
```

The above works, but I wished there was a better solution instead of this hack.

Comment: Are you actually using `R` for the case class? Because in your example it seems redundant.

Comment: Yes. I am using it in my program (for comprehension). I write CSV parsing Scripts and usually the pattern is same. So, I wanted to reuse my case class and write only the Programs and Interpreters for my scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `CSVRecord` has nothing to do with `A`, the compiler has no evidence that `String <:< A`. If this compiles, you'll be able to create a `ProcessCSV[Int]` and pass it to `StringInterpreterOfCSV.apply`, which doesn't make sense.

If `CSVRecord` had a type parameter `R`, and `get(2)` returned `R`, then it would work:

```
case class ProcessCSVRecord[R](csvRecord: CSVRecord[R]) extends ProcessCSV[R]
```

Otherwise you can `csvRecord.get(2).asInstanceOf[A]`.